# Multiplication table 1 x 1 = 1 | 1 x 2 = 2 | 1 x 3 = 3 using 2d array Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, multiplication

I'm a beginner in Javascript and need to create multiplication table using 2d array. The result should be The result should be as below:
1 x 1 = 1 | 1 x 2 = 2 | 1 x 3 = 3. I have below variables which I can't modify. Can someone help?

const n = 3;
const calc = [];

```
for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < n; j++) {
    }
}console.log(calc);
```

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
function calc(n){
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
       console.log(`${i} * ${j} = ${i*j}`)
    }
}
}
calc(3)
```

Comment: Thank you but is there a way to solve without function as I haven't done it yet?

Comment: Yes , Remove the 1st line. then Remove the last 2 lines. and finally change every  'n' to a number , lets say change it to 3, so you can see the same results as this example.  the  'n' are both located in the 2 for loops